# Sort/filter nodes based on relation properties

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

Given the following graph:

[image]

1. How do I get the nodes adjacent to `node[5]` with `weight > 50`?
2. How do I get the nodes adjacent to `node[5]` with label `"knows"`, sorted by weight?

Comment: what do you mean by related ?

Comment: adjacent is the term use in graph terminology

Comment: Thanks! Updated question for future reference

Comment: may i ask what was the program that you used to make this diagram? thanks.

Comment: @royv the super awesome [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. **How do I get the nodes linked to node[5] with an edge with a label "knows" and a weight > 50 ?**

   g.v(5).outE('knows').filter{it.weight > 50}.inV

Depending on the relation/edge direction it might be "inE" instead of outE or "both" step then you will need to adjust the query since you will have edges in the other direction or edges in both directions...

1. **How do I get the nodes related to node[5] with label "knows", sorted by weight?**

   g.v(5).outE('knows').filter{it.weight > 50}.sort{a,b -> a.weight <=> b.weight}.toList()._.inV

Comment: #1 works, #2 raises the following error: `No such property: inV for class: java.util.AbstractList$ListItr`

Comment: what version of Neo4j and Gremlin are you using? You are getting back a List there, you probably need to turn it into a pipe with _() or so before being about to treat it with further steps.

Comment: Im on 1.4.1, il try upgrading to 1.6 and trying it out.

Comment: g.v(5).outE('knows').filter{it.weight > 50}.sort{it.weight}.reverse()._().inV

Answer (score 12):

Not sure about Gremlin, but in Cypher it is:

## 1:

```
START s=node(5) MATCH s-[r]-f WHERE r.weight > 50 RETURN f
```

## 2:

```
START s=node(5) MATCH s-[r:knows]-f RETURN f ORDER BY r.weight
```

If you care about the direction of the relationship, put arrows on the relationships, like "s-[]->f" or "s<-[]-f"

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a gremlin query.

Comment: Ah, okay. Go with abki's answer then, with the change suggested by Peter. Any particular reason for going with Gremlin over Cypher for this purpose?

Comment: Personally, I find Cypher cleaner, and simpler to understand, but the project im working on, uses gremlin.

Comment: Hey Josh, do you know by any chance if searching by relationship property really slows down the Cypher query?